# Using same CFLAGS on Makefile.am in each subdirectories (sub-make)

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I have a project with a Makefile.am in each of the multiple subdirectories.

How do you propagate a `AM_CFLAGS` variable setting from that parent Makefile.am to other subdirectories' Makefile.am (sub-make)?

I'm aware of the following methods:

- `export` a variable
- `include` statement to a common `${top_srcdir}/Makefile_cflags.am` file.
- `MAKEFLAGS`

Recursive make is not an option and I'm shying away from `include` and `MAKEFLAGS` statement approaches.

The GNU manual doesn't seem to clearly outline about propagating compiler/linker settings to sub-make.

Comment: Perhaps something about propagating `make -e` as outlined in http://www.tack.ch/gnu/make-3.82/make_85.html#Options-Summary ?

Comment: There is this section about communicating to sub-make but it is 'recursion':
http://www.tack.ch/gnu/make-3.82/make_43.html#Variables_002fRecursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is a `autoconf`/`configure.ac` solution after all. GNU calls it `outputting a variable`.

To propagate the `CFLAGS` from the parent `Makefile` to each and every sub-makes (subdirectories' `Makefile), I added the following lines to`configure.ac`:

> AC_SUBST(AM_CFLAGS)

Then for each sub-make, I added the following line to 'import' that variable:

> AM_CPPFLAGS = @AM_CPPFLAGS@

Then executed an `autogen.sh` to rebuild both `configure.in`, `Makefile.in` and `Makefile`.  Then executed `configure` and it propagated the `AM_CFLAGS` then and there.

Also a useful solution for `AM_CPPFLAGS`, `AM_CXXFLAGS`, and `AM_LDFLAGS` as well.

More details of `AC_SUBST` given here: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html

Comment: This answer seems very confused.  Yes, if you want multiple autotools-generated Makefiles to all have variables with a given name and value, then one way to accomplish it is via the `AC_SUBST()` macro in Autoconf.  But that does not forward the variable or value from one `Makefile` to another, nor do you have to manually put anything in any of your `Makefile.am` files to make it work (automake does that part for you).  Instead, the generated `configure` script will insert it directly into each of the generated `Makefile`s.